# React setState not updating

Tags: javascript, setstate

```
handleSkipThisQuestionClicked = () => {
    const { answersDict, currentIndex, currentQuestionGroupId } = this.state;
    if (currentIndex < answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId].length - 1) {
        this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId][currentIndex + 1]);
    } else {
        // set current index to 0 and increase the current group
        debugger;
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            currentQuestionGroupId: prevState.currentQuestionGroupId + 1,
            currentIndex: 0,
        }));
        this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[this.state.currentQuestionGroupId][0]);
    }
};
```

In this code in the `else` block, when the setState function is called, the state doesnot change

Note: Even if it is asynchronous it doesn't change it all after a long time

Could this problem be because of the ES6 destructuring of the state

**EDIT**

I logged and checked with a callback and still the state remains unchanged

```
handleSkipThisQuestionClicked = () => {
        const { answersDict, currentIndex, currentQuestionGroupId } = this.state;
        if (currentIndex < answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId].length - 1) {
            this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId][currentIndex + 1]);
        } else {
            // set current index to 0 and increase the current group
            debugger;
            this.setState(
                (prevState) => ({
                    currentQuestionGroupId: prevState.currentQuestionGroupId + 1,
                    currentIndex: 0,
                }),
                () => {
                    console.log(this.state.currentQuestionGroupId);
                    console.log(this.state.currentIndex);
                },
            );
            this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[this.state.currentQuestionGroupId][0]);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does `setQuestionDetails` set state as well?

Comment: Without seeing more of your component we can only really guess what's going wrong here. But I'm suspicious of that final call: `this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[this.state.currentQuestionGroupId][0])`, because the `this.state.currentQuestionGroupId` will still take the "old" value at that point. I don't know what `setQuestionDetails` does but you may well be unintentionally "resetting" to the old "question group" here.

Comment: No, it just makes an API Call

Comment: @RobinZigmond There are no state changes in ```setQuestionDetails```
Let's say i want to make a call to ```setQuestionDetails``` with the updated values, even the callback logged the prevState values

Comment: "how do i make sure the state is updated" - you mean, how do you make sure the state is updated before you do something next? The callback argument to setState is how you do that, which you've shown in your second snippet - if that's not working, there's a deeper problem, but it's hard to know what without seeing a reproducible example of your code. Could you perhaps make a simple codesandbox to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: You should add a breakpoint to see what that condition is doing because you may not even be changing state if that condition isn't met.

Comment: Sorry man @RobinZigmond would love to but i am  on a deadline now ,Giovanni Esposito answer worked out, but i am curious why didnt it work in callback
Thanks for the help man

Comment: @Andy i checked with the debugger, the code block is being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always copy the state in local var, make changes and set again the state. Something like:

```
handleSkipThisQuestionClicked = () => {
    const { answersDict, currentIndex, currentQuestionGroupId } = this.state;
    if (currentIndex < answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId].length - 1) {
        this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[currentQuestionGroupId][currentIndex + 1]);
    } else {
        // set current index to 0 and increase the current group
        debugger;
        let result = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        result.currentQuestionGroupId++;
        result.currentIndex = 0;

        this.setState({ result });
        this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[result.currentQuestionGroupId][0]);
    }
};
```

Comment: @SanjayKapilesh happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, because `setQuestionDetails` relies on the state being up to date you should use `setState`'s callback function.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  currentQuestionGroupId: prevState.currentQuestionGroupId + 1,
  currentIndex: 0,
}), () => this.setQuestionDetails(answersDict[this.state.currentQuestionGroupId][0]);
```